# cannot ssh at all to remote host -- options?

Tags: ssh, security, password, key-authentication, vps

**Update**:  *Not sure why the downvote.  In any event, after umpteen tries I did briefly connect with ssh.  I logged out, but cannot login again, ssh just hangs.  This was with keyless ssh to a user account.*

*Now it works fine.  Just took a long time before I could login.  **Why**?*

I [disabled password based ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334485/ssh-works-but-ssh-copy-id-stalls-connection-timed-out), but may have inadverdently disabled key based authentication:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ ssh -vvv thufir@foo.example.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "foo.example.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to foo.example.com [123.123.123.12] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 123.123.123.12 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host foo.example.com port 22: Connection timed out
thufir@doge:~$ 


thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ ssh -vvv root@foo.example.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "foo.example.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to foo.example.com [123.123.123.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to foo.example.com:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from foo.example.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1546/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:A/1ufRNwhmB0KfYD5HFRAlrtYgVt2vnv1W4YNkNAs6s
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from foo.example.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 123.123.123.12
debug1: Host 'foo.example.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/thufir/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 1589/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55933276ea90), agent
debug2: key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/thufir/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
thufir@doge:~$
```

There's nothing in particular on the VPS, I can just re-install.  What other options do I have?  the remote host runs CentOS.

Comment: The remote host may run something like `fail2ban` or `sshguard`?

Comment: You should check the logs.

Comment: It is unclear to me what "Not sure why the downvote" does have to do in a question about U&L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few common failure (or slowness) causes, on the server side (the host you connect to):

- dns problems? on some systems the DNS is used when connecting to check infos on the connecting client : a broken DNS then makes the initial login via ssh slow : try to see if adding a line with   "IP.OF.YOUR.CLIENT  a_name" in /etc/hosts  boosts the logins? (this is just to test, but not a solution : in general it is then bets to FIX the DNS and delete that added line from /etc/hosts once it works again reliably.)
- memory problems? You usually get a "cannot fork" or similar process when the sshd process tries to initiate your shell environment... You don't seems to be in this case

And there can be many more types of failures: check the logs on the server (and client) sides, enable more verbose levels if you can (if you are administrator of those serveurs)